# How to count number of rows altered by Series.str.replace?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, count

I have a dataframe with column comments, I use regex to remove digits. I just want to count how many rows were altered with this pattern. i.e To get a count on how many rows `str.replace` operated.

```
df['Comments'] = df['Comments'].str.replace('\d+', '')
```

Output should look like

```
Operated on 10 rows
```

Comment: Would it be cheating to just save off `df['Comment']` and perform a comparison between the old and new values after, counting the differences?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Nope, it's the only way to do it.

Comment: I have considered it and it is my last resort if no one is able to answer a better solution :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
import re
op_regex = re.compile("\d+")
df['op_count'] = df['comment'].apply(lambda x :len(op_regex.findall(x)))
print(f"Operation on {len(df[df['op_count'] > 0])} rows")
```

Using findall which return list of matching strings.

Comment: this is working. But i do have operation where i also perform lower case only. I guess i will figure that bit out. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

re.subn() method returns the number of replacements performed and new string.

Example: text.txt contains the following lines of content.

```
No coments in the line 245
you can make colmments in line 200 and 300
Creating a list of lists with regular expressions in python ...Oct 28, 2018
re.sub on lists - python
```

Sample Code:

```
count = 0   
for line in open('text.txt'):
    if (re.subn(r'\d+',"", line)[1]) > 0:
        count+=1
print("operated on {} rows".format(count))
```

**For pandas:**

```
data['comments'] = pd.DataFrame(open('text.txt', "r"))
count = 0
for line in data['comments']:
    if (re.subn(r'\d+',"", line)[1]) > 0:
        count+=1

print("operated on {} rows".format(count))
```

Output:

```
operated on 3 rows
```

Comment: OP does not want to get the count of replacements, only the count of rows where the replacement occurred.

Comment: I have modified my answer, please check

Comment: yes, in pandas also by using regex we can get the count of rows where replacement occurred. I have modified my answer, Please check.Hope the answer meet your requirement

Comment: I am sorry I did try the pandas one, but it still giving operations count instead of rows count.

Comment: If possible, Could you please share the code which you tried?