# Number of replacements performed by str.replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd have expected to find at least a question on this subject, instead... nothing.

I am writing a script for the smart patching of a project, so I have a dictionary where keys are file paths and values are lists of tuples, and each tuple is an original/replacement pair. I loop on files, slurp each file, apply changes to the contents, rename the original, and write the changed contents to the original name. Pretty standard stuff.

The changes I have to apply were for a two month old version of the project, so I decided I did not want to use diff and patch: the sections I am changing now may have moved by many lines, but they *shouldn't* be changed – mostly.

This means I have to check that each diff **is** correctly applied – but it seems there is no way to obtain the number of replacements from `str.replace()`.

Of course I can compare the string before and after the replacement, but this seems inefficient, and does not allow to check the number of replacements performed.

Annoyingly, regexps have a `subn()` method that does exactly this, but my patterns may contain lots of special characters, so using regexps would be a pain. And apparently there is no equivalent method for strings.

I'm going to write a function to do a search/replace in a loop for each replacement – but it seems a sort of an overkill... Does anybody have a better idea?

EDIT: oh, here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56659742/how-to-count-no-of-operations-performed-by-str-replace), but the replacement pattern is a regex, so `re.subn()` is an acceptable solution...

Comment: `str.replace` takes a parameter `count` which controls the maximum number of occurrences to replace.

Comment: @Wolric, I do not want to limit the number of replacements, I want to check if there is more than one...

Comment: @mkrieger1, maybe not an overkill – but it's certainly an unnecessary complication, given that `str.replace()` certainly *knows* the number of replacements... it's somewhat frustrating.

Comment: @mkrieger1, yes, `str.count()` is indeed better than a loop, and certainly more efficient.

Comment: "Lots of special characters" is not a problem for regex, just apply `re.escape()` to your pattern to make all characters be treated as literal matches.

Comment: @jasonharper, thank you!, that's another interesting trick to add to my bag'of tricks :)